# I can't solve this derivative problem which contains $\cos x$ and $\sin x$

Tags: derivatives

I want to calculate the derivative of the following function
$$ y = {(\cos x - 1)}^{\sec x - 1}$$

I searched and found a video on YouTube which started solving this by applying natural logarithm in both sides.
$$ \ln (y) = \ln {(\cos x - 1)^{\sec x - 1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{y'}{y} = (\sec x - 1).[\ln(\cos x - 1)]$$
Here is the part I do not understand. Since we used natural logarithm we must have
$$\cos x - 1> 0 \Rightarrow \cos x > 1$$

For logarithm to be well defined, however it is impossible for any x. So, I don't know whether the video from YouTube made a mistake or whether my reasoning has some flaw I can't find. Please help me understand the mistake and calculate the derivative properly!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed the exponential with negative base is not well defined. Isn't it $\cos(x-1)$? Can you give the link for the video?

Comment: Note that your statement after the $\implies$ sign is not correct because you have differentiated the left hand side but not the right hand side containing the contentious logarithm term

Comment: To have an easier algebra, you can substitute $u=\cos x$ but your problem of logarithm being non-definite will remain.

Comment: I guess you can still use the rule but the function $y$ is inherently complex

Comment: The guy speaks Portuguese, so I guess you guys won't understand it (by the way, I've realized just now that I've written ''secx'', where it should be ''sinx''). Anyway, here's the link: https://youtu.be/x8D3RmWxhWM

Comment: Why not just differentiate directly?

Comment: Dear Diego, the video is wrong because the domain of the function, as written, is the set $\{2\pi n : n \in \mathbb N\}$, and you can't differentiate a function that isn't defined on an open set. The author's steps are correct, but that's assuming that the function he has is a differentiable function at all! There's a comment under the video now, which says that some kind of modulus has to be taken. The resulting calculation is unclear to me. Your reasoning has no problems, well done!

Comment: I see now, thanks for the reply!